# XPath structure not working

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

In my site, a field has the following XPath (strange for me at the first sight but well):

`/html/body/aside/div/ul/li[2]/a/span`

So I am using this way:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/aside/div/ul/li[2]/a/span]")).click();
```

But it's not working and the error message is:

> The string `'/html/body/aside/div/ul/li[2]/a/span]'` is not a valid
>   XPath expression.

Could you help me, please? Thank you :)

Comment: share the relevant HTML and stop writing /html/body/aside/div/ul/li[2]/a/span as Xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/aside/div/ul/li[2]/a/span")).click();
```

Comment: Thank for your help but this way is not working, I am receiving the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

You had a `]` in the end of your string. Remove this and it will work.

On a side not it is not necessary to write the `/html/body/`. You could shorter the XPath by using

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//aside//div//ul//li[2]//a//span")).click();`

Comment: On the other hand, `/html/body/aside/div/ul/li[2]/a/span` is *much* more efficient than `.//aside//div//ul//li[2]//a//span` since it doesn't have to do backtracking and checks fewer elements, and generally avoids problems if the same construct for some reason appears in different locations in the document. Just go for `/html/body/aside/div/ul/li[2]/a/span`, and it's only 3 characters longer, so the shortening argument isn't very strong.

Comment: (a) the two expressions aren't equivalent: the form with `.//aside` will match more elements than the form with `/html/body/aside`. (b) You don't know which is more efficient without measuring it: it depends on the XPath implementation.

Comment: Thank for your help but this way is not working, I am receiving the same error :(